# How does ThreadPoolExecutor interrupt the idle threads?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I just went through the source code of `ThreadPoolExecutor` found that it will interrupt all idle workers once the time is up to the set value of keepAliveTime and allowCoreThreadTimeOut is true.

It's a little strange to me it can only invoke the interrupt method when runState >= SHUTDOWN:

The code below is from the method `getTask()` of `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

```
Runnable getTask() {
...
if (workerCanExit()) {
    if (runState >= SHUTDOWN) // Wake up others
        interruptIdleWorkers();
    return null;
   }
}
```

Does that mean all the idle threads can only be interrupted when the runState >= SHUTDOWN (SHUTDOWN, STOP or TERMINATED)? That's to say they will be not interrupted when the state is RUNNING.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. This `getTask()`  method in the `ThreadPoolExecutor` is called on to gets the next task for a worker thread to run. This code block is only executed when the method call has not identified any Runnable task for execution. So, if nothing is found to execute, it must check for the shutdown state.

from java doc of `workerCanExit()`

> Check whether a worker thread that fails to get a task can exit. We allow a worker thread to die if the pool is stopping, or the queue is empty, or there is at least one thread to handle possibly non-empty queue, even if core timeouts are allowed.

Comment: I think runState is the state of ThreadPoolExecutor. It can only be changed by shutdown method. e.g. I created a ThreadPoolExecutor with the core pool size of 10 and maxmun pool size of 100, and keepAliveTime of 1 minute. I offer 100 tasks to the executor in order to make its pool size reach 100. After a certain time. 50 of the 100 tasks complete. That means 50 of the threads are idle now. But the runState is RUNNING. Will these idle threads end after 1 minute?

Comment: @Jacky; No, they will not, It defines time for idle threads waiting for work. Threads use this timeout when there are more than `corePoolSize` present or if `allowCoreThreadTimeOut`. Otherwise they wait forever for new work.

Comment: in the example, the corePoolSize is 10 which is lower than 100. the task queue is ampty while 50 workers are working. Why not the 50 idle threads exit since we allowCoreThreadTimeOut ?

Answer (score 1):

As an example, configure ThreadPoolExecutor as : corePoolSize=1, maxPoolSize=5, workQueueSize=1, keepAliveTime=60s, allowCoreThreadTimeOut=false.

When you offer 5 tasks(each task is time-consuming) concurrently, one of the 5 tasks will enter into  workQueue, other 4 tasks will be handled immediately by 4 worker threads newly created almost at the same time.

At this time, the sum of worker threads is 4(workerThreadCount=4). Once one thread completes its task, it will be waiting on workQueue by invoking blocking method, workQueue.take() or workQueue.poll(keepAliveTime). As for which blocking method will be invoked is decided by the workerThreadCount.

For example(Hypothesis), at a time point, workerThread-0 is handling task-0; task-1 is staying in workQueue; workerThread-1 is handling task-2; workerThread-2 is handling task-3; workerThread-3 is handling task-4, and workerThreadCount==4.

1. workerThread-3 completes task-4, and this time [workerThreadCount==4] > [corePoolSize==1], it will get next task(task-1) from workQueue by workQueue.poll(keepAliveTime). Then, go on handling task-1, and this time workerThreadCount==4. The code segment of ThreadPoolExecutor.java as following:

   `while (task != null || (task = getTask()) != null) {
       task.run();
   }
   private Runnable getTask() {
       boolean timed = allowCoreThreadTimeOut || wc > corePoolSize;
       Runnable r = timed ? workQueue.poll(keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS) : workQueue.take();
   }`
2. then workerThread-0 completes task-0, because of [workerThreadCount==4] > [corePoolSize==1], it still get next task from workQueue by workQueue.poll(keepAliveTime). But, this time workQueue is empty, so workerThread-0 will be blocked on it, and the state of workerThread-0 is **TIMED_WAITING**. Once keepAliveTime elapsed, workQueue.poll(keepAliveTime) will return null, next,  workerThread-0 will return from Runnable.run(), and turn into **TERMINATED**. This time workerThreadCount==3.
3. then workerThread-1 completes task-2, it will return by the same way as workerThread-0. This time workerThreadCount==2.
4. then workerThread-3 completes task-1, it will return by the same way as workerThread-1. This time workerThreadCount==1.
5. then workerThread-2 completes task-3, but this time [workerThreadCount==1] not more than [corePoolSize==1], so it will be blocked when get the next task from workQueue by workQueue.take() until there is a available task in workQueue. And its state is **WAITING**.

NOTE : the source code comes from JDK8.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly. A correct task(if interruptions are allowed) must checks itself for interrupted flag and terminate (i.e. return from run()).